# DataLoader returns multiple values sequentially instead of a list or tuple

Tags: pytorch, dataset, dataloader

```
def __init__():

def __len__():

def __getitem__(self, idx):    
    cat_cols = (self.cat_cols.values.astype(np.float32))
    cont_cols = (self.cont_cols.values.astype(np.float32))
    label = (self.label.astype(np.int32))
    return (cont_cols[idx], cat_cols[idx], label[idx])
```

When I used the dataloader in the above class, I get the cont_cols, cat_cols and label as outputs with index 0, 1 and 2. Whereas I want them together. I have tried returning values as dictionary but then I have indexing issues.

I have to read the output of dataloader as

```
dl = DataLoader(dataset[0], batch_size = 1)



for i, data in enumerate(dl):
    if i == 0:
       cont = data
    if i == 1:
       cat = data
    if i == 2:
       label = data
```

Currently my output for

```
for i, data in enumerate(dl):
   print(i, data)
```

is

0 tensor([[3.2800e+02, 4.8000e+01, 1.0000e+03, 1.4069e+03, 4.6613e+05, 5.3300e+04,
0.0000e+00, 5.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 1.0000e+00, 2.0000e+00, 7.1610e+04,
6.5100e+03, 1.3020e+04, 5.2080e+04, 2.0040e+03]])

1 tensor([[ 2.,  1.,  1.,  4.,  2., 17.,  0.,  2.,  3.,  0.,  4.,  4.,  1.,  2.,
2., 10.,  1.]])

2 tensor([1], dtype=torch.int32)

What I want is the output to be accessed by data[0], data[1] and data[2] but the dataloader gives me back only data[0]. It is returning the cont_cols first, then cat_cols and then label.

Comment: I'm not sure I catch where you're going. Currently, you have a dataset that returns, for a given index, a tuple containing three elements: `cont`, `cat`, and `label`. What do you mean by together? Do you want to return `cont[0]`, `cont[1]`, and `cont[1]`. Please clarify your problem statement.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it is better now. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused here, your dataset can indeed return *tuple*s but you have to handle it differently.

Your dataset is defined as:

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__():
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, idx):    
        cat_cols = (self.cat_cols.values.astype(np.float32))
        cont_cols = (self.cont_cols.values.astype(np.float32))
        label = (self.label.astype(np.int32))
        return (cont_cols[idx], cat_cols[idx], label[idx])
```

Then you define your dataset and data loader. Note, you should not provide `dataset[0]` here, but instead `dataset`:

```
>>> dataset = Dataset()
>>> dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1)
```

Then access your dataloader content in a loop:

```
>>> for cont, cat, label in dl:
...   print(cont, cat, label)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood now. i was trying to check only for 1 row, if it works.